# How to clear the content of a label with code in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, label

I want to clear the content of a label with swift code when the simulator first start, not with the interface builder of Xcode. How do I do that? Anybody can help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried self.myLabel.text = ""

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
textLabel.text = nil
```

since textLabel**.text** is a Optional String.

Comment: But my label code in the ViewController file looks like this: @IBOutlet weak var showName: UILabel! It's an implicitly unwrapped optional, it cannot be initialized to nil.

Comment: you set the .text to nill not the var itself.

Comment: I know what you mean, but where should I put this statement? When I put after @IBOutlet weak var showName: UILabel! An error occurs and says that 'expected declaration'.

Comment: If you want to reset it only once every time your view loads, then put it in the viewDidLoad()

Comment: i am glad it has helped you.

Answer (score 4):

Use this,

```
yourLabel.text = ""
```

or

```
yourLabel.text = nil
```